# 301 Redirect root without cascading new root directory to all other 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have successfully redirected the root of my site to a sub-directory in another site:

```
#Redirect Root to subdirectory on example.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/subdirectory [L]
```

I'm running into trouble with all of my other redirects. The sub-directory of the new root (/subdirectory) is getting inserted into my redirects before each path, which is resulting in broken redirects.

Example:

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ https://www.example.com/company/contact.shtml
```

tries to point to

```
https://www.example.com/subdirectorycompany/contact.shtml
```

In a nutshell, I can either get the root working, or I can get the redirects working -- but not both. Can anyone please lend some insight?

I have read a bunch of posts, which is how I have gotten as far as I did, but I could use some help, please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `Redirect` directive and `RewriteRule` as they are from different Apache modules and are invoked at different times.

It is better to have all your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# all specific 301 redirects go here
RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ https://example.com/company/contact.shtml [L,NC,R=301]

#Redirect Root to subdirectory on example.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/subdirectory [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I just used this syntax on all 300 of my redirects but got an internal server error. What did I do wrong?

    ReRewriteEngine On
 
    RewriteRule ^contact-us/?$ https://example.com/company/contact.shtml [L,NC,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^/foodquality?$ https://www.etq.com/industries/food-and-beverage [L,NC,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/subdirectory [L,R=301]

Comment: Reason of 500 error is usually some typo error. Check apache error.log to see where the syntax error is.

Comment: Hi Anubhava. So, everything works great in my DEV environment -- going from relative paths to absolute paths in production, but when I move .htaccess to production, my redirects don't work there. Do you have any insights?

Comment: If no redirects are working in prod then either .htaccess or mod_rewrite may not be enabled

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. It's been extremely helpful. It's working in prod now, but only when I leave out the trailing slash at the end of the url. I'll keep reading and see if I can figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the final issue. I made all of the slashes at the end of my relative paths optional by adding ? before the slash. Now my directs work with or without the slash.